# Access a list within Pandas Dataframe apply function without making list global

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have a Pandas dataframe. For each row in this frame I want to make a certain check. If the check yields `True`, then I want to add certain columns of the dataframe-row to a list-structure.

How can I access a list from within the apply function without the need to create a global list variable? Is this possible? Or is there a better way to do this?

The code looks like this:

```
df.apply(checkFunction, axis=1)

checkFunction(row): 
    if (check == True):
        myList.append(row)
    return row
```

Comment: If need arguments to `apply` - check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12183507/2901002)

Comment: If it is not dupe, let me know, I reopen question.

Answer (score 1):

[`df.apply()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) allows you to pass positional arguments and keywords.

```
def checkFunction(row, lst): 
    if (check == True):
        lst.append(row)
    return row

my_list = []
df.apply(checkFunction, axis=1, args=(my_list,))
```

Don't call it `list`, that collides with the reserved `list` keyword.

NOTE: The value passed to `args` must be a tuple. I just edited the sample code to show this.