# Python pandas: apply a function to dataframe.rolling()

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

I have this dataframe:

```
In[1]df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15],[16,17,18,19,20],[21,22,23,24,25]])
In[2]df
Out[2]: 
    0   1   2   3   4
0   1   2   3   4   5
1   6   7   8   9  10
2  11  12  13  14  15
3  16  17  18  19  20
4  21  22  23  24  25
```

I need to achieve this:

1. for every rows in my dataframe,
2. if 2 or more values within any 3 consecutive cells is greater than 10,
3. then the last of that 3 cells should be marked as True.

The resulting dataframe df1 should be same size with True of False in it based on the above stated criteria:

```
In[3]df1
Out[3]: 
    0   1      2      3      4
0 NaN NaN  False  False  False
1 NaN NaN  False  False  False
2 NaN NaN   True   True   True
3 NaN NaN   True   True   True
4 NaN NaN   True   True   True
```

- df1.iloc[0,1] is NaN bacause in that cell, only two numbers were given but needed atleast 3 numbers to do the test.
- df1.iloc[1,3] is False since none in [7,8,9] is greater than 10
- df1.iloc[3,4] is True since 2 or more in [18,19,20] is greater than 10

I figured dataframe.rolling.apply() with a function might be the solution, but how exactly?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: @penguin2048 I edited the post, my question is how to achieve 1 2 3 4 in the post.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: please post the expected output

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan I re-phrased the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are right that using `rolling()` is the way to go. However, you must keep in mind since `rolling()` replaces the value at end of the window with the new value, so you can not just mark the window with `True` you will also get `False` whenever the condition is not applicable

Here is the code that uses your sample dataframe and performs the desired transformation:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15],[16,17,18,19,20],[21,22,23,24,25]])
```

now, defining a function that takes a window as an argument and returns whether the condition is satisfied

```
def fun(x):
    num = 0
    for i in x:
        num += 1 if i > 10 else 0
    return 1 if num >= 2 else -1
```

I have hardcoded the threshold as 10. So if in any window the numbers of values greater than 10 are greater than or equal to 2 than the last value is replaced by 1 (denoting True), else it is replaced by -1(denoting False).

If you want to keep threshold parameters as variables, then have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12183507/5695235) answer to pass them as arguments.

Now applying the function on rolling window, using window size as 3, axis 1 and additionally if you don't want NaN then you can also set min_periods to 1 in the arguments.

```
df.rolling(3, axis=1).apply(fun)
```

produces the output as

```
  0   1    2    3    4
0 NaN NaN -1.0 -1.0 -1.0
1 NaN NaN -1.0 -1.0 -1.0
2 NaN NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0
3 NaN NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0
4 NaN NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your explaination, what if I need to the threadhold(0 in your  if i > 0) and greater than 1(1 in your if num > 1) both as argument of the function, how do I rewrite 'df.rolling(3, axis=1, min_periods=1).apply(fun)'? Function in .apply takes more than self as argument?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12182744/python-pandas-apply-a-function-with-arguments-to-a-series?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa check this

Answer (score 3):

Use `sum` on a boolean dataframe.

```
df.gt(10).rolling(3, axis=1).sum().ge(2)

       0      1      2      3      4
0  False  False  False  False  False
1  False  False  False  False  False
2  False  False   True   True   True
3  False  False   True   True   True
4  False  False   True   True   True
```

You can nail down the exact requested output by masking where na.

```
df.gt(10).rolling(3, axis=1).sum().pipe(lambda d: d.ge(2).mask(d.isna()))

    0   1      2      3      4
0 NaN NaN  False  False  False
1 NaN NaN  False  False  False
2 NaN NaN   True   True   True
3 NaN NaN   True   True   True
4 NaN NaN   True   True   True
```

Answer (score 0):

You need -

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15],[16,17,18,19,20],[21,22,23,24,25]])
df1 = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series([np.nan, np.nan]+[all(j>10 for j in i) for i in zip(x[0::1], x[1::1], x[2::1])]), axis=1)

print(df1)
```

**Output**

```
0   1      2      3      4
0 NaN NaN  False  False  False
1 NaN NaN  False  False  False
2 NaN NaN   True   True   True
3 NaN NaN   True   True   True
4 NaN NaN   True   True   True
```

**Explanation**

```
list(zip(x[0::1], x[1::1], x[2::1])
```

breaks it down to taking 3 columns at a time for every row -

```
0             [(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 5)]
1            [(6, 7, 8), (7, 8, 9), (8, 9, 10)]
2    [(11, 12, 13), (12, 13, 14), (13, 14, 15)]
3    [(16, 17, 18), (17, 18, 19), (18, 19, 20)]
4    [(21, 22, 23), (22, 23, 24), (23, 24, 25)]

all(j>10 for j in i)
```

Checks for each element in the list of tuples and then outputs `True` if all the elements in the tuple are greater than 10

Concatenating `[np.nan, np.nan]` to match your output. Hope that helps.