# How to apply function to dataframes with arguments?

Tags: python, pandas

`apply` method in `pandas.DataFrame` has signature like this:

`DataFrame.apply(func, axis=0, broadcast=False, raw=False, reduce=None, args=(), **kwds)`

If I have a function with parameter, how can I pass this function to `apply`?
For example, the function is:

`def foo(x, activation = 3.0):
    ...
    return calculated_val`

When I set `args = 5`, there is an error says, `*args` must be an iterable.

Comment: Use `df.apply(foo, args=(5,))` ?

Comment: See this answer from the dup target https://stackoverflow.com/a/43460506/2336654