# Pandas create a new column containing calculated results, applied onto mutliple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I need some help to modify my function and how to apply it in order to iterate an ifelse condition through multiple features.

Suppose we have the following table `t1`

```
import pandas as pd
names = {'name': ['Jon','Bill','Maria','Emma']
         ,'feature1': [2,3,4,5]
         ,'feature2': [1,2,3,4]
         ,'feature3': [1,2,3,4]}
t1 = pd.DataFrame(names,columns=['name','feature1','feature2','feature3'])
```

I want to create 3 new columns based on an ifelse condition. Here is how I am doing it for the first feature:

```
# Define the conditions
def ifelsefunction(row):
    if row['feature1'] >=3:
        return 1
    elif row['feature1'] ==2:
        return 2
    else:
        return 0

# Apply the condition
t1['ft1'] = t1.apply(ifelsefunction, axis=1)
```

I would like to write the function into something iterable like this

```
def ifelsefunction(row, feature):
    if row[feature] >=3:
        return 1
    elif row[feature] ==2:
        return 2
    else:
        return 0

t1['ft1_score'] = t1.apply(ifelsefunction(row, 'feature1'), axis=1)
t1['ft2_score'] = t1.apply(ifelsefunction(row, 'feature2'), axis=1)
t1['ft3_score'] = t1.apply(ifelsefunction(row, 'feature3'), axis=1)
```

---- EDIT ----

Thanks for the answers, I may have over-simplified the actual problem.

How do I do the same for this conditions?

```
def ifelsefunction(var1, var2):
    mask1 = (var1 >=3) and (var1<var2)
    mask2 = var1 == 2
    return np.select([mask1,mask2], [var1*0.7, var1*var2], default=0)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python pandas: apply a function with arguments to a series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12182744/python-pandas-apply-a-function-with-arguments-to-a-series)

Answer (score 1):

I think here is best avoid loops, use [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) for test and assign mask only for selected columns from list, for pass function with input `DataFrame` is used [`DataFrame.pipe`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html):

```
# Define the conditions
def ifelsefunction(df):
    m1 = df >= 3
    m2 = df == 2
    return np.select([m1, m2], [1, 2], default=0)


cols = ['feature1','feature2','feature3']
t1[cols] = t1[cols].pipe(ifelsefunction)
#alternative
#t1[cols] = ifelsefunction(t1[cols])

print (t1)
    name  feature1  feature2  feature3
0    Jon         2         0         0
1   Bill         1         2         2
2  Maria         1         1         1
3   Emma         1         1         1
```

For new columns use:

```
# Define the conditions
def ifelsefunction(df):
    m1 = df >= 3
    m2 = df == 2
    return np.select([m1, m2], [1, 2], default=0)


cols = ['feature1','feature2','feature3']
new = [f'{x}_score' for x in cols]

t1[new] = t1[cols].pipe(ifelsefunction)
#alternative
#t1[new] = ifelsefunction(t1[cols])

print (t1)
    name  feature1  feature2  feature3  feature1_score  feature2_score  \
0    Jon         2         1         1               2               0   
1   Bill         3         2         2               1               2   
2  Maria         4         3         3               1               1   
3   Emma         5         4         4               1               1   

   feature3_score  
0               0  
1               2  
2               1  
3               1
```

EDIT:

You can change function like:

```
def ifelsefunction(df, var1, var2):
    mask1 = (df[var1] >=3) & (df[var1]<df[var2])
    mask2 = df[var1] == 2
    return np.select([mask1,mask2], [df[var1]*0.7, df[var1]*df[var2]], default=0)


t1['new'] = ifelsefunction(t1, 'feature3','feature1')
print (t1)
    name  feature1  feature2  feature3  new
0    Jon         2         1         1  0.0
1   Bill         3         2         2  6.0
2  Maria         4         3         3  2.1
3   Emma         5         4         4  2.8
```

Comment: Thanks, this works well for my example.

However, I might have a made a mistake of oversimplifying my actual problem. The conditions need to rely on more than 1 feature, and the expected output is a computation of 2 features. - I've made an edit to the original question, please help if you can!

Comment: @Gabriel - Answer was edited.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `apply`

```
t1["ft1_score"] = t1.feature1.apply(lambda x: 1 if x >= 3 else (2  if x == 2 else 0))
t1["ft2_score"] = t1.feature2.apply(lambda x: 1 if x >= 3 else (2  if x == 2 else 0))
t1["ft3_score"] = t1.feature3.apply(lambda x: 1 if x >= 3 else (2  if x == 2 else 0))
```