# How to apply a function that takes multiple arguments to a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-apply

I want to create two functions, apply those functions on the DataFrame, and return the result to column interval_ratio

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
max_testing_data = sns.load_dataset('geyser')
max_testing_data = max_testing_data[max_testing_data.groupby('waiting')['duration'].transform('max') == max_testing_data['duration']]
median = max_testing_data.groupby('kind', as_index=False)['waiting'].median()
print(median)
       
def short_modifier(waiting, duration):
    max_testing_data['interval_ratio'] = max_testing_data['duration']/max_testing_data['waiting']

def long_modifier(duration, waiting):
    max_testing_data['interval_ratio'] = max_testing_data['waiting']/max_testing_data['duration']

max_testing_data.apply(short_modifier, axis=0)
max_testing_data.apply(long_modifier, axis=0)
```

I am getting an error:

> short_modifier() missing 1 required positional argument: 'duration'

How can I fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python pandas: apply a function with arguments to a series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12182744/python-pandas-apply-a-function-with-arguments-to-a-series)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said which line the error is from, but am I corrent to believe it is the penultimate one?  As Nathan directs, the problem is that you are missing the argument "duration" for you function.  More information about `.apply()` can be found [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).

Without needing to use `.apply()`, you could instead write the following:

```
max_testing_data["interval_ratio"] = max_testing_data["duration"] / max_testing_data["waiting"]
```

This will produce the same result as the function `short_modifier()`.